# Is the Schwartz space a tame Frechet space?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, examples, metric-spaces, schwartz-distributions

I ran into the following definition of [tame Frechet spaces and Nash-Moser therem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash%E2%80%93Moser_theorem#Tame_Fr%C3%A9chet_space).

It says that the space of smooth functions on a compact manifold is tame Frechet.

However, I wonder if

> The Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ is also a tame Frechet space, even if $\mathbb{R}^N$ is not compact.

At least I was able to show and got confirmed that [the Schwartz space is a graded Frechet space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4866758/finding-a-set-of-graded-seminorms-on-the-schwartz-space).

However, according to the definition of tame Frechet spaces stated in the top link, I have to find some Banach space $B$ and maps $L : \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^N) \to \Sigma(B)$, $M: \Sigma(B) \to \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ with required "boundedness" property.

I stronlgy suspect that $B = L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^N)$ with
\begin{equation}
L(f) := \bigl( e^{-e^{k-1}} f \bigr)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}
\end{equation}
must somehow work. However I have difficulty finding the appropriate $M : \Sigma(B) \to \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^N)$.

Could anyone please help me fill in all the details? I have not copied every definition from the link [tame Frechet spaces and Nash-Moser therem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash%E2%80%93Moser_theorem#Tame_Fr%C3%A9chet_space), but I will do so if anyone requests for the sake of completeness.

Comment: $\mathscr S$ is isomorphic to the space $s$ of rapidely decreasing sequences which itself is isomorphic to the space of smoooth functions on the circle $S^1$. You find these isomorphisms, e.g., in the book *Introduction to Functional Analysis* of Meise and Vogt.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth By isomorphism, you mean a surjective linear isometry between Frechet spaces?

Comment: @JochenWengenroth But even with an isometry, I don't clearly see how the "tame structure", as described in [tame Frechet spaces and Nash-Moser therem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash%E2%80%93Moser_theorem#Tame_Fr%C3%A9chet_space), can be preserved. As you can see, seminorms are involved in the definition.

Comment: You are right -- but you did not specify a grading on$\mathscr S(\mathbb R^N)$. Dietmar Vogt worked a lot about graded Fréchet spaces.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth I already did in the post :  [the Schwartz space is a graded Frechet space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4866758/finding-a-set-of-graded-seminorms-on-the-schwartz-space)

Comment: @JochenWengenroth I found exactly the same question and your answer there: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/359760/is-mathcals-mathbbrn-a-tame-fr%C3%A9chet-space

Comment: @JochenWengenroth and I still do not understand your argument and the book by Vogt does NOT address the issue of tameness...

Comment: I give just a small hint, without any further clarification, *even if requested*: Read pages 557−560 from the famous(?) Kriegl−Michor book from 1997.

Comment: @TaQ I just figured it out. Thank you.